# mocking JNDI DNS interface

Tags: unit-testing, jndi

I have a project where we use JNDI to query DNS records. The project itself is working greatly, however I could not find a simple and independent way of testing the JNDI dependent components using a jUnit.

The code is far from rocket science and looks pretty much like the typical vanilla JNDI DNS request.

Presently I point the test units to a public DNS records (A, MX, TXT records) but this is sort of a no go.

```
    ...
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
    env.put("com.sun.jndi.dns.timeout.initial", timeOut);
    env.put("com.sun.jndi.dns.timeout.retries", retries);
    env.put("java.naming.provider.url", dns:);
    }

    Attributes attrs;

    try {
        DirContext ictx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        attrs = ictx.getAttributes(queryInput, new String[]{queryType});
        return attrs;
    } catch ( NameNotFoundException e) {
        getLogger().debug("Resolution for domain {} failed due to {}", new Object[]{queryInput, e});
        attrs = new BasicAttributes(queryType, "NXDOMAIN",true);
        return attrs;
```

Is there a way of injecting the TXT and A responses into JNDI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be one can use traditional JNDI mock strategies (like using `Mockito.when`) but nail the condition to getAttributes method as seen in the sample code below:

```
@Before
public void setupTest() throws Exception {
    this.queryDNS =  new QueryDNS();
    this.queryDNSTestRunner = TestRunners.newTestRunner(queryDNS);

    Hashtable env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, FakeDNSInitialDirContextFactory.class.getName());

    this.queryDNS.initializeContext(env);

    final DirContext mockContext = FakeDNSInitialDirContextFactory.getLatestMockContext();

    // Capture JNDI's getAttibutes method containing the (String) queryValue and (String[]) queryType
    Mockito.when( mockContext.getAttributes(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(String[].class)))
            .thenAnswer(new Answer() {
                public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                    // Craft a false DNS response
                    // Note the DNS response will not make use of any of the mocked
                    // query contents (all input is discarded and replies synthetically
                    // generated
                    return craftResponse(invocation);
                }
            });
}
```

And

```
// Dummy pseudo-DNS responder
private Attributes craftResponse(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
    Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();
    String querySubject = arguments[0].toString();
    String[] queryType = (String[]) arguments[1];

    // Create attribute
    Attributes attrs = new BasicAttributes(true);
    BasicAttribute attr;

    switch (queryType[0]) {
        case "AAAA":
            attr = new BasicAttribute("AAAA");
            attrs.put(attr);
            break;
        case "TXT":
            attr =  new BasicAttribute("TXT", "666 | 123.123.123.123/32 | Apache-NIFI | AU | nifi.org | Apache NiFi");
            attrs.put(attr);
            break;
        case "PTR":
            attr = new BasicAttribute("PTR");
            attr.add(0, "eg-apache.nifi.org.");
            attr.add(1, "apache.nifi.org.");
            attrs.put(attr);
            break;
    }
    return attrs;
}
```

Hope this helps people in the future.